# how to save ASP.NET_SessionId in custom membership providers

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, membership

I use the custom membership providers for my web site. and use this code for login:

```
private User SetupFormsAuthTicket(string userName, bool persistanceFlag)
    {
        User user;
        UsersContext usersContext = new UsersContext();
            user = usersContext.GetUser(userName);

        var userId = user.UserId;
        var userData = userId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, //version
                            userName, // user name
                            DateTime.Now,             //creation
                            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), //Expiration
                            persistanceFlag, //Persistent
                            userData);

        var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
        return user;
    }
```

but i check cookie in my browser, just saved ASPXAUTH and not saved ASP.NET_SessionId

I want save ASP.NET_SessionId but persistanceFlag is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to persist the authentication ticket, you need to explicitly set the cookie Expires same as authentication ticket expiration.

```
....

var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);

if (authTicket.IsPersistent)
{
    cookie.Expires = authTicket.Expiration;
}

Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```